# Using XSLT to create elements where there are no corresponding elements as hooks

Tags: xml

I have a long HTML table that I am transforming to XML and breaking up into sections.

Abbreviated source:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category title</th>
        <th>Parameter name</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Values</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="category">Category A</td>
        <td class="paramname">Parameter 1</td>
        <td class="lvl">1</td>
        <td class="values">1-100</td>
        <td class="description"><p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="category">Category A</td>
        <td class="paramname">Parameter 2</td>
        <td class="lvl">2</td>
        <td class="values">2-200</td>
        <td class="description"><p>Every good boy does fine.</p>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="category">Category B</td>
        <td class="paramname">Parameter 3</td>
        <td class="lvl">3</td>
        <td class="values">3-300</td>
        <td class="description"><p>Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="category">Category B</td>
        <td class="paramname">Parameter 4</td>
        <td class="lvl">4</td>
        <td class="values">4-400</td>
        <td class="description"><p>This has been a test of the emergency broadcast system.</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Desired output:

```xml
<xml>
    <section>
        <title>Category A</title>

        <para><emphasis><heading>Parameter Name: Parameter 1</heading></emphasis></para>
        <para>Level: 1</para>
        <para>Values: 1-100</para>
        <para>Description: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.</para>

        <para><emphasis><heading>Parameter Name: Parameter 2</heading></emphasis></para>
        <para>Level: 2</para>
        <para>Values: 2-200</para>
        <para>Description: Every good boy does fine.</para>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>Category B</title>

        <para><emphasis><heading>Parameter Name: Parameter 3</heading></emphasis></para>
        <para>Level: 3</para>
        <para>Values: 3-300</para>
        <para>Description: Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.</para>

        <para><emphasis><heading>Parameter Name: Parameter 4</heading></emphasis></para>
        <para>Level: 4</para>
        <para>Values: 4-400</para>
        <para>Description: This has been a test of the emergency broadcast system.</para>
    </section>
</xml>
```

The problem is in detecting when the `category` changes, and creating `section` elements in the output stream to enclose those categories.

I have figured out the first part of this problem--detecting category changes, and the first and last `tr`. But XSLT does not allow one to emit fragments of xml with only closing or opening tags, so I am not sure how to solve the second part of this problem. The following fragment was my first stab, but this doesn't work:

```xml
    <xsl:for-each select="tr">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tr[1]">
            <section><title><xsl:value-of select="td[@class='category']" /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="tr[last()]">
            <xsl:apply-templates/></section>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[@class='category'] !=td[@class='category']">
            </section><section><title><xsl:value-of select="td[@class='category']" /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each><!-- tr -->
```

It seems as if I need to buffer the output until I get to a category breakpoint, at which point I would enclose the buffer contents in `section` tags, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I'd do it differently: Collect all distinct categories e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812122/distinct-in-xpath) (easier if the entries are ordered by category), then `foreach` over all categories, emit section and title, `foreach` over all nodes with the category, emit rest. Much cleaner, and keeps the tag nesting.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, I'll play around with that approach. The entries will be ordered by category, so I've got that going for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XSLT 2.0, and learned of `for-each-group`, which dramatically simplifies this.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xml>
<xsl:for-each select="//table">
<xsl:for-each-group select="tr" group-by="td[@class='category']" >
    <section><title><xsl:value-of select="td[@class='category']" /></title>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <!-- handling for individual tr omitted -->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:for-each>

    </section>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each>
</xml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```